# Can we define a subscriber for multiple Grails events

Tags: events, grails, groovy

I am new to the grails framework. Currently using version 4.0.12. I have one requirement where I want to subscribe to multiple grails events with a single subscriber method, for e.g.,

```
@Subscriber('*-*')
anyMethod () {
    // TO DOs
}
```

How can we achieve something like above using regex or any other alternative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.